# Cant view children of a list when hideininspector in custom inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inspector

i have a little issue in Unity, so i made a List and a bool
[image]
 and i scripted it so that when the bool is pressed, the list is revealed 
[image]
 And here, you can see that i can open the list with no problem and view the contents
[image]
But, i wanted the original to not show,so i added [HideInInspector]
[image]
But now when i press the bool, it shows the list, BUT, i cant view nor edit the content of list
 [image] 
 How do i fix this?
Thanks!
P.S: Here is my code

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();
        QuizManager myScript = target as QuizManager;
        if (myScript.ShowList) {
            var property = serializedObject.FindProperty("AList");

            serializedObject.Update();

            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(property,true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your problem is connected with using `[HideInInspector]`. I can suggest a couple of possible solutions for your trouble:

1. Try not using `[HideInInspector]` and remove `DrawDefaultInspector()` from your code. Just make `EditorGUILayout.PropertyField()` for all properties in your class and then you'll be able to add this bool variable as you want.
2. Try using technique, described [here](http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/editor/custom-list/).
3. Try using `CustomPropertyDrawer`, you can get official information on it [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html) and [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-PropertyDrawers.html)

Comment: 1.I tried that, but for some reason then i can't toggle the bool, nor change anything in the list
2.That page is kind of long, is there a specific segment?, or do
 i have to skim through it?(if there is no other solution i will read it all)
3.From what i read, this is making your own manual list(with labels and everything), is there a faster way?
Thanks!

Comment: 1 to make changes you need to use serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties(); otherwise unity will erase changes. 2 the whole article is a tutorial, it's a workaround kinda like customPropertyDrawer. 3 this is way which is most convinient when you need a lot of custom features serializing something

Comment: Thank you so much "serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();" works :D